# Could someone summarise the dative shift (him/ to him) for me, in words a non linguist can understand?

Tags: grammar

Can someone explain to me why, depending on the position of the pronoun (?), a preposition is un-/necessary, and why those two options are only possible with some verbs?

Ex.:

I gave *him* it.            I gave it *to him*.
I wrote *him* a letter.     I wrote a letter *to him*.

*I acquired *him* a new car.  I acquired a new car *for him*.

Answer (score 1):

Some verbs can take two objects.  Some verbs can't  (you need to learn which ones can take two objects - you can't work it out).

Verbs that can take two objects include "give" and "write".  The rule is simple enough.  You can either use two objects and  write

> Give <recipient> <thing>

or use a prepositional phrase headed by "to"

> Give <thing> to <recipient>

In the first case we know which is the recipient by the order of the objects. In the second case, the recipient is marked as the object of the preposition.

As "acquire" isn't a verb that can take two objects (I remind you, there is *no* logic to this), "I acquired him a new car" is incorrect.

"Why" is a fairly meaningless question in grammar. You could trace this grammar back through Anglo Saxon, Proto-german and even to Proto Indo European, but there is no logical reason "Why".

Comment: Thank you, James!

Comment: If you think this has answered the question, you can click the green mark next to the answer to accept it, and earn a couple of points of reputation in the process.